# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' in Swift 3 Error

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Converted my syntax to Swift 3. When I did, I got the error with this code

```
open override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if keyPath! == "animatingTab" && change!["new"]!.isEqual(NSNumber (value: 2 as Int))// here i got error{

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.settingsView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: LayoutService.width(widthPercentage: 20), y: 0)
            self.settingsView.setShadows()
        }, completion: nil)

    }
    else if keyPath! == "animatingTab" && !change!["new"]!.isEqual(NSNumber(value: 2 as Int))// here i got error {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.settingsView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: LayoutService.width(widthPercentage: 100), y: 0)
            self.settingsView.clearShadows()
        }, completion: nil)

    }

    if keyPath! == "currentUser" {
        self.settingsView.profileView.buildProfileForUser(user: AccountService.sharedInstance.currentUser!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the full error message and the line where it occurs

Answer (score 0):

The value of parameter `change` is `Any`, the compiler cannot infer that it's supposed to be `Int`. You have to cast the type accordingly.

The most reliable solution is to optional bind all values and use the appropriate property of `NSKeyValueChangeKey`:

```
if let path = keyPath, path == "animatingTab"
   let new = change?[.newKey] as? Int, new == 2 {  ...
```